# Random Numbers; Converting list to string

Tags: python, string, list, random, numbers

My assignment is to make a random number generator in the form of a coin flip.  As this is somewhat of a starting class, at this point of the term, I am only allowed to use certain built in functions.  I was aided by a link the instructor gave us that helped me understand the current code I'm using to generate that list. Here is the code used to generate the list:

```
userin = int(input("enter the number of coin flips: ")
coin = ['H', 'T']
userlist = (random.choices((coin), k=userin))
```

Now, I was storing the randomly generated list into `userlist` because I am to also print it as a list.  Seems simple enough.  I've tried printing it as list, but I'm assuming since I have it coded this way, it will always print it in list format.  I know this is simple, and the goal after this will take even more work, but my mind is stuck on this. I will eventually have to count how many "heads" and "tails" were generated, thus the string.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Please clearly state what question you are asking.

Comment: If you want to convert your list to a string, you can use `s = "".join(userlist)`. You can, for example, count the number of heads by using the builtin function: `count('H')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eric.  Sorry for the jumbled question. I was mainly asking how to convert the list into  a string and print it, manipulate it, etc.  But for some reason I couldn't use the str() function, which I thought would work.  I also think my instructor will disallow the .join() function, but at this point I don't see another way.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**I think what you are looking for is something along the lines of this:**

```
import random

try:
    userin = int(input("Enter the number of desired coin flips: "))

except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Input")

coin = ['H', 'T']
userlist =(random.choices((coin), k=userin))

print('You flipped '  + str(userlist.count('H')) + ' Heads and ' + str(userlist.count('T')) + ' Tails.')

print(userlist)

k=""

for x in range(0, len(userlist)):

    k=str(k) +"" + str(userlist.pop())

print(k)
```

This is assuming you just want to print the results of the coin flips. Added a try loop at the start in case an integer is not entered. Make sure to import random so that it works as well, also added a missing parentheses at the end of your input statement. Used the list.count() function to find the number of T's or H's in userlist. Also just using str() in your print should work. Hopefully this will serve your purposes.

Comment: Thanks Charles! I like the counting method you used to find the number of heads and tails.  The assignment asks for a printed list and also a printed string, and for some reason when trying essentially what you have here earlier, it just printed two lists instead of a "list" and a "string". (This was using str(userlist))  For whatever reason, it just prints the same.

Comment: @relytkadReh printing userlist on its own and with with str(userlist) should just return the same thing. Has my example solved your question or could you clarify what else you are looking for?

Comment: Well in a way.  I want it to look something like this: ['H', 'H', 'H', 'T'] and HHHT.  But when using str(userlist) it just prints it as a list still.  The reason I bring it up again is because as I said, I don't think the instructor will accept the .join() method.  But your help is appreciated, regardless.

Comment: @relytkadReh Edited my code so now it should work for you. Just created a new string and individually added the strings in the list to the new string. This code does not hold the values of the list after it returns them though. Let me know if it works. : )

Comment: Thank you, thank you!  You've helped.  I've been tinkering with the next part which is moving through that randomly generated string and finding the longest running pattern of both H's and T's.  I don't want you to do the assignment for me, but if you want to think about it I would appreciated continuing the conversation.  <3